# How to change default image in tree node with GeoExt

Tags: openlayers-2, geoext, ext-js

I'm using GeoExt to create a tree. In each node I want the corresponding image at left instead of the default image [image: default image]  like [this site](http://todosmiscomercios.com.ar/). How can I do it?

**Edit**

I found [this example](http://api.geoext.org/1.1/examples/tree-legend.html) but I don't know how can I add childrens

**Edit 2**

This is part of my code:

```
var bpn = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS("bpn", 
    url,
    {
        LAYERS: [ 'Año 2004', 'Año 2005', 'Año 2006', 'Año 2007', 'Año 2009'],
        format: "image/png",
        transparent: "true",
        projection: 'EPSG:4326'
     },
     {
         buffer: 0, 
         displayOutsideMaxExtent: true,
         isBaseLayer: false,
         displayInLayerSwitcher: false,
         yx: {'EPSG:4326' : true}
      });

var treeConfig = [
    {
        nodeType: "gx_layer",
        layer: bpn,
        isLeaf: false,

        loader: {
            param: "LAYERS",

        },
        expanded: false
    }];

tree = new Ext.tree.TreePanel({
    border: true,
    region: "west",
    title: "Entre Ríos",
    width: 250,
    split: true,
    collapsible: true,
    collapseMode: "mini",
    autoScroll: true,

    loader: new Ext.tree.TreeLoader({
        applyLoader: true,
        uiProviders: {
            "layernodeui": LayerNodeUI
        }
    }),
    root: {
        nodeType: "async",
        children: treeConfig
    },     
    rootVisible: false,
    lines: false,
});
```

Each layer (node)`'Año 2004', 'Año 2005', 'Año 2006', 'Año 2007', 'Año 2009'` has a different image. What should I change in `treeConfig`?

Answer (score 1):

For each of your nodes add an iconCls option, the iconCls refers to some css

nodeType: "gx_layer",
layer: "xyz",
iconCls: "cc_xyz",

and the css might look like this

.cc_xyz { background-image: url( /_images/parcel_sm.png ) !important; }